# How to add data as subcollection to all user's document in firebase flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

These are the users from my 'LoanFriends' collection:

[image]

And these are the data that I want to add inside of each user.

[image]

This is my Cloud Firestore screenshot:

[image]

how do I create different data sub-collections for each user that I add?
What I did right now resulted in me getting the same data for different users which is not right.

Comment: You need to add a sobcollection for the existing users? Or for the one who are newly added?

Comment: The users are created by a list.view builder. I want to add a subcollection to each and every users. What I mean is every user must have subcollection of ReceivedLoanData and GaveLoanData.

Comment: Ok, but you want to add to your existing data or to what will be new from now on?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new , what I want is to store the collection "GaveLoanData" and "ReceivedLoanData" inside each "LoanFriends" collection's user. I hope I clarified enough for you to understand my problem

Comment: Do you want to for the existing data or for the new data?

Comment: ok, for the existing data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my question:

> Do you want to add subcollections for the existing data or for the new data?

And your answer:

> ok, for the existing data.

To solve this, you have to iterate the entire "LoanFriends" collection, read the documents, and for each document that you find, you have to make a `.collection('ReceivedLoanData')` and `.collection('GaveLoanData')` call. Right after that, chain a [add()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/add.html) function call to add the desired documents right under each subcollection.

**Edit:**

According to your last comment:

> Can you explain what I had to do if it were for a new data

Then you have to create another reference:

```
var receivedLoanDataRef = db.collection("LoanFriends").document(docId)
                            .collection("ReceivedLoanData");
```

And add the data a accordingly:

```
receivedLoanDataRef.add(data);
```

Comment: Can you explain what I had to do if it were for a new data

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: okay the new data was the one I was looking for, can you explain how I access the document ID for each different LoanFriends' document. It seems like I created a the subcollection as you mentioned but the data of that subcollection i.e amount and details are same in each document which is ridiculous

Comment: Without seeing the entire code that you are using, I cannot be much of a help. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I have mentioned my problem clearly and the code too which generated the problem in my question. Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69750219/16453337

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.